# Remove specific code from html source code automatically at specific date or time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to remove some code from my HTML source code at specific date or time like if I want to remove some code at 25-10-2019 so after that date code should be removed from source code.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo Html code</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>some demo parragraph content</p>

<!-- This code should be removed after 25-10-2019-->
<script type="application/ld+json"> { "@context" : "http://schema.org/", "@type" : "JobPosting" }
    </script>
<!-- code end here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, what exactly doesn't let you do it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very practical to remove source code dynamically (although doable at a very slow speed), what I would do is create a table of job postings (or whatever else it is you want to hide after a certain amount of elapsed time) in a database and only retrieve rows from the DB that are still active. This can either be via evaluating the date or manually setting boolean values for an `active` column (the code is for the second approach specifically; dynamically evaluating the dates works the same its just your condition in the SQL statement that differs).

```
public static function getActiveJobPostings() {
    $conn = new PDO( db_host, db_user, db_pw );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM jobpostings WHERE active = true ORDER BY closingdate ASC";

    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->execute();
    $list = array();

    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
      $job = new JobPosting( $row );
      $list[] = $job;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
    $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
}

$postings = JobPosting::getActiveJobPostings();
foreach($postings['results'] as $ad) {
//retrieve class variables like $ad->closingdate
echo '<script type="application/ld+json"> { "@context" : "http://schema.org/", "@type" : "JobPosting" }
</script>'
}
```

For this however you need to first create an accompanying class that stores the table's column values as class variables, so that you have an object for each selected row.

Comment: i'm using blogspot any way to remove code in blogger